# Xml Serialization for Akna services

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, xml-serialization

We are using [Akna](http://www.akna.com/) services to send email marketing for our customers. Those emails are sent by posting a xml to Akna services. The basic xml structure is:

```
<main> 
    <emkt trans="20.05">
        <acao>[TITLE]</acao>
        <destinatario>
            <email>[EMAIL]</email
        </destinatario>
        <destinatario>
            <email>[EMAIL]</email
        </destinatario>
    </emkt>
 </main>
```

What I've done so far is to define a class and decorate it with Xml Attributes. However I couldn't figure out how to always insert the tag **emkt** after **main** tag and encapsulate everything inside it.

```
public class Destinatario
{
    [XmlElement("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("main")]
public class ContatoComAcaoPreDefinidaAgendamento
{
    [XmlElement("acao")]
    public string Acao { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("destinatario")]
    public List<Destinatario> Destinatarios { get; set; }        
}
```

To serialize I'm using this method below

```
public static string ToXml<T>(this T target) where T : class
{
    var x = new XmlSerializer(target.GetType());
    var textWriter = new StringWriter();
    var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");

    x.Serialize(textWriter, target, ns);
    return textWriter.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` serializes your class hierarchy to your XML element hierarchy.  Thus, there needs to be an intermediate class contained inside `ContatoComAcaoPreDefinidaAgendamento` that can map to the `emkt` element.  However, you can use proxy properties in your top level class to hide the existence of this intermediate class, getting and setting its properties directly, if that would be more convenient:

```
public class Destinatario
{
    [XmlElement("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Emkt
{
    public Emkt()
    {
        Trans = "20.05";
    }

    [XmlAttribute("trans")]
    public string Trans { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("acao")]
    public string Acao { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("destinatario")]
    public List<Destinatario> Destinatarios { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("main")]
public class ContatoComAcaoPreDefinidaAgendamento
{
    Emkt emkt;

    [XmlElement("emkt")]
    public Emkt Emkt
    {
        get
        {
            // Auto-allocate.
            if (emkt == null)
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref emkt, new Emkt(), null);
            return emkt;
        }
        set
        {
            emkt = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Acao { get { return Emkt.Acao; } set { Emkt.Acao = value; } }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<Destinatario> Destinatarios { get { return Emkt.Destinatarios; } set { Emkt.Destinatarios = value; } }
}
```